# Cakephp-Calling Parent render() function from Appcontroller gives Error: Call to a member function send() on a non-object

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to build a piece of application using cakephp; which will generate output in multiple formats (xml, json, custom, html).

Based on certain property, output format will be decided.
What I want is, if html is output ype; then I want application to render view as usual (Regular Controller->render); else data should be rendered in other formats

Here is what I am trying to do.
I have overridden function render in AppController.php as following -

```
public function render($view = null, $layout = null) {
    if ($this->rType == "json") {
        $this->_renderJson();
    } else if ($this->rType == "xml") {
        $this->_renderXml();
    } else if ($this->rType == "custom") {
        $this->_renderCustom();
    } else {
        parent::render($view,$layout);
    }
}
```

This works perfectly with other formats but html.

I want call should be forwarded to Controller::render as normal cakephp flow would do. Instead it gives me below error

Error: Call to a member function send() on a non-object File: /xx/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php Line: 174

Any thoughts - how can I resolve this ?

Comment: Your whole effort is pretty pointless because the framework already supports what you try to do see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html You just re-invent the wheel and broke it.

Comment: why the heck you downvoted this for ??
In my case - json and xml given here are just to show the point... I have 3 other custom propriatory formats I need to render this to ... so my efforts are very good up to the point.
And dont just downvote the question because you got the reps ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When overwriting things you must make sure that your overriden method matches the original implementation with regards to the arguments that it takes and values that it returns.

Your `render()` method lacks the proper return value, which should be an instance of `CakeResponse`, which is used later on by the dispatcher.

**https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.6.0/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php#L930**

**https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.6.0/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php#L174**

So, change your custom rendering methods to return `$this->response`, and add appropriate returns in the overwritten `render()` method:

```
public function render($view = null, $layout = null) {
    if ($this->rType == "json") {
        return $this->_renderJson();
    } else if ($this->rType == "xml") {
        return $this->_renderXml();
    } else if ($this->rType == "custom") {
        return $this->_renderCustom();
    } else {
        return parent::render($view,$layout);
    }
}
```

Comment: That works ndm .... adding return to that statement did the trick.. I wonder how did I miss it.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Adding return to the Controller::render() statement did the trick indeed as told by ndm.
Also, one more work around I found was to use beforeRender().

```
public function beforeRender(){
    parent::beforeRender();
    if ($this->rType == "json") {
        $this->_renderJson();
        return false;
    } else if ($this->rType == "xml") {
        $this->_renderXml();
        return false;
    } else if ($this->rType == "custom") {
        $this->_renderCustom();
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}
```

This worked as well....

thanks.